# Bizarre behaviour in simple Delphi code

Tags: delphi

I am passing TProcessItem structure as a return value from my function. While in GetProcessFromHandle function, the ExeFile property of the structure returned by FindByID, contains the expected executable name, but in the structure returned by GetProcessFromHandle it somehow becomes empty. I added two Messageboxes to demonstrate it. Is anyone able to explain what is happening here?

```
function GetProcessFromHandle(hWnd: HWND): TProcessItem;
var
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInfo;
  PID: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := nil;
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, @PID);
  ProcessInfo := TProcessInfo.Create(nil);
  try
    Result := ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses.FindByID(PID);
    if Assigned(Result) then ShowMessage(Result.ExeFile); //first message
  finally
    ProcessInfo.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  Process: TProcessItem;
begin
  Process := GetProcessFromHandle(FindWindow(nil, 'My App'));
  if Assigned(Process) ShowMessage(Process.ExeFile); //second message
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `TProcessInfo` object owns the `TProcessItem` object that `GetProcessFromHandle()` is returning a pointer to.  As such, when the `TProcessInfo` object is freed, so is the `TProcessItem` object, and thus the pointer being used by `Test()` is invalid.  So you run into **undefined behavior**.  You are lucky your code did not just crash instead.

If you want to return the path to the EXE file, return only that value, eg:

```
function GetProcessExeFileFromHandle(hWnd: HWND): string;
var
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInfo;
  ProcessItem: TProcessItem;
  PID: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '';
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, @PID);
  ProcessInfo := TProcessInfo.Create(nil);
  try
    ProcessItem := ProcessInfo.RunningProcesses.FindByID(PID);
    if Assigned(ProcessItem) then
      Result := ProcessItem.ExeFile;
  finally
    ProcessInfo.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  ProcessExeFile: string;
begin
  ProcessExeFile := GetProcessExeFileFromHandle(FindWindow(nil, 'My App'));
  ShowMessage(ProcessExeFile);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I somehow thought that when I return TProcessItem like that, a copy of it is being made.

Comment: @forsajt If you were using a `record` (aka `struct` in other languages), then yes, that would be the behavior. Otherwise, any type of `class` will always be a pointer.

Comment: @forsajt To add to what Jerry said. If you had used a record, you also wouldn't destroy it with `Free`.

Comment: @CraigYoung And in most cases, you wouldn't even `Create` it either.